# Do Villagers count towards the passive mob total with respect to animal spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

With regard to [mob spawning](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Mob_spawning), a 17 chunk by 17 chunk area centered around the player will have a passive mob cap of 11, meaning that if there are 11 or more passive mobs (i.e. animals) in that area, no new passive mobs will spawn. [Villagers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager) do appear under the [passive mob list](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Passive#Passive), but they have very different spawning behavior than animals do (i.e. they will not randomly spawn, and can only be created either at world generation, through villager breeding, or by curing zombie villagers).

So, for the purpose of animal spawning, are Villagers counted towards the passive mob total? In other words, if I had nothing except 11 Villagers in an area, would no animals spawn at all there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the percentages of mobs spawning in Chunks?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131044/what-are-the-percentages-of-mobs-spawning-in-chunks)

Comment: This question can be asked as a comment on the linked question.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I have to disagree, totally different question.  Moreover, this question does not have an obvious answer on the Wiki.

Comment: @John "Do villagers count as passive?" easily fits in the scope of "Mob spawning limits for chunks"

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Spawn mechanics for villagers are totally different than spawn mechanics for everything else (for starters, they have nothing to do with chunks). What I'm not sure about is the crux of this question: whether the totally-different spawn mechanics of villagers are completely *independent*, or whether they're affected by other creatures.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It doesn't matter.  This question is just asking for clarification on an existing answer.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I'm just going to flat-out say you're wrong. I'll happily vote to reopen if this closes, and I'm pretty sure four others will too.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie "What are mob spawning percentages for chunks?" vs "Do villagers count as passive mobs for spawning?"  I don't see how that can be anything other than asking for clarification.

Comment: Here's something to consider: both Endermen and Wolves are listed as neutral mobs, yet Endermen spawn through hostile mob code while wolves have animal spawning code. Furthermore, Endermen count for the hostile mob cap, wolves the passive. Therefore, what category the wiki puts them in has no bearing on villager's spawn mechanics. (The reason: the categories on the wiki are by their behaviour to the player, not how the code treats them. The spawn mechanics farther down the page are code-based; so the two are actually completely unrelated. That should be clarified on the wiki.)

Comment: @OrigamiRobot The downside of folding this question and its answer into the other is that this specific information will potentially become harder to find in that much broader question and answer. Anyone specifically wanting to know if animal spawning is affected by a villager population may not find it very easily.

Comment: @gnovice Combining these two questions would actually make that _easier_ to find.  All the information would be in one place rather than two.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Villagers are not passive mobs (as animals are). They are not related in the code. They are not spawned the same. They are not spawned in per-chunk percentages. An answer treating them as passive mobs in the other question would get downvoted as *wrong*. Nobody will look for villager spawn mechanics in a question about animals, therefore it would be harder to find burying it in the same question.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm not saying you should do that.  I'm saying you should point out exactly what you just said in your existing answer.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot It never would have occurred to me to do so, nor would it make sense for me to do so now, because **they are completely unrelated**.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie They obviously are confusable as evidenced by _this_ question.  Let's stop clogging up the comments section and discuss this in [chat].

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I am not interested in discussion. This objection is misguided, as it seems to misunderstand the point of the question. There is the very slightest chance that villagers count toward the passive cap (though it is unlikely), but it would be a *weird* thing for it to be true. I'm not going to put a non-sequitur like "Oh, and a ribbon vendor is called a 'haberdasher'," in the other answer, nor am I going to make a non-sequitur about villagers there.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I'll be in the Minecraft chat room.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You're the one who is misunderstanding.  I am not nor have I ever claimed that villagers _do_ count towards the spawn limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some watching and waiting, I found the answer myself. Villagers **do not** appear to count towards the passive mob total.

I discovered this while playing Skyblock 2.1 in Minecraft 1.6.2. I had managed to amass 7 villagers, 3 cows, 3 sheep, 1 pig, and 1 chicken in my quaint sky village. If villagers counted towards the passive mob total, this would have put the total at 15 and kept any new passive mobs from spawning. However, I had another pig spawn. Even now with 3 cows, 3 sheep, 3 pigs, and 1 chicken (for a total passive mob count of 10, 1 less than the cap), I still get new animals spawning on occasion. Villagers appear to only be categorized as "passive" in name only, and are treated as separate with regard to passive mob (i.e. animal) spawning.